# Using a separate migration project for F# data layer

Tags: c#, .net, f#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to setup migrations for my EF Core project on **F# .NET 4.7.2**. Currently I have the following data context:

```
type MyContext  =
    inherit DbContext

    new() = { inherit DbContext() }
    new(options: DbContextOptions<MyContext>) = { inherit DbContext(options) }

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable apples: DbSet<AppleEntity>
    member x.Apples
        with get () = x.apples
        and set v = x.apples <- v
```

Setting up my initial migration using `Add-Migration Initial -Context Application.MyContext` told me that F# is not a supported language for generating migrations, which is why I set up a C# project with a reference to the F# project.

However, when running the add migration command from this project, EF Core cannot find my context class: `No DbContext named 'Application.MyContext' was found.`

On [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) about using a separate migration project, the following tip is stated:

> If you have no existing migrations, generate one in the project containing the DbContext then move it. This is important because if the migrations assembly does not contain an existing migration, the Add-Migration command will be unable to find the DbContext.

But this is not a possibility for me, given that the context is in an F# project. Anyone have a clue on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by creating a C# version of MyContext and running the `Add-Migration` command. Then I deleted it and changed the reference in both `MyContextModelSnapshot.cs` and `Initial.designer.cs` to my F# data context.

Answer (score 1):

EF is not F# friendly and AFAIK it's not in their near plan to improve the support for other languages. If you need migrations you have to use another framework like DbUp or another ORM like Linq2DB, Dapper. Easier option is to define the data layer in C# and reference it from other F# project